# Correct english word for undoing a knot: untangle, disentangle, untie?

Tags: word-request, academic-writing

What's the best English word to describe the undoing of a knot? Some I have in mind: untangle, disentangle, untie.

I would like to use this word as an adjective. Here is an example sentence:

> After undoing the knot, the string became **untangled**.

What's the best word to use here? Is it *untangle*, *disentangle*, or *untie*? Something else? I will use this in academic writing, so my question is what is the "most correct" choice, and the most immediately understandable.

UPDATE. Another possibility: [unknot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unknot)

Comment: When creating a knot, do you tangle it, entangle it or tie it?

Comment: What do you want to say about the string that "undoing the knot" doesn't already say? Sometimes when I untie a knot, I make a mistake and the string becomes 'entangled'. It also depends on what you mean by a 'knot'? Is it neatly tied or is it a tangle? If the latter, you don't so much untie the knot but untangle it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I want an adjective, see the example sentence. What word can I use in place of the one in bold? If "untangle" is correct, that's also fine (I just want to confirm it is correct)

Comment: @KillingTime Are you asking me? I'm not a native English speaker, so I'd like someone else opinion.

Comment: As I asked, is the knot in the string already a tangle, or is it a neat formal knot?

Comment: The point is that _undoing/untying_ a knot results in two straight pieces of string, so you don't need to refer to disentangling the string - _unless_ it was tangled _as well as_ tied in a knot.

Comment: The thing is that after untying the knot, the string doesn't _become_ anything, the _knot_ is now untied, but the string remains a string as it was before, so it is hard to think of a word that would fit. Can you give us more context? Is this a single piece of string with a knot? Is the knot connecting two pieces of string? Connecting the string to something else? Please clarify what property of the string you want to describe.

Comment: Here's [a string with a single knot](https://www.123rf.com/photo_81856072_string-of-red-rope-knot-isolated-on-white-background.html) I'd say **untie the knot** or **undid the knot** and here are some [tangled shoe laces](https://www.freeimages.co.uk/galleries/home/general/slides/abstractlaces.htm) **He untangled his laces** seems the best fit

Comment: "After undoing the knot“ sounds perfectly reasonable to my ears, you could add "the string was loose".

Comment: knots and tangles are two different realities.

Comment: After undoing the knot, the string **straightened out**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Knot" is usually used for something deliberately done. In this case the knot is "tied" when it is created and "untied" when removed. "Undid" would also be acceptable. "Untangled" would be wrong.

> Adam tied the knot, and Belle untied it later.

More rarely a knot can refer to an accidental entanglement. When undoing that "untangled" is normal and acceptable. "Unknotted" would also be acceptable. "Untied" would be wrong, since it was never tied.

> Belle had some knots in her hair, and Adam untangled them.

"Tangle" almost always means an accidental linking, which is why it isn't used of deliberately tied knots.

The sentence you quote is looking for an adjective. You could use "untangled" in the second case (undoing an accidental tangling).

> Belle had some knots in her hair, but Adam got her hair untangled.

If your example sentence involves a deliberate knot then "unknotted" is best (though it makes the sentence weird). "Completely unknotted" works if this was the last of a series of knots.

It's possible that the knot was the thing preventing the undoing of an accidental Tangle, in which case your sentence does make sense.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with "unknotted"!

Comment: @a06e as mentioned, "unknotted " works but it is wierd to say "After undoing the knot, the string became unknotted". It's a bit like saying "After I knotted my laces, the laces were knotted."

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but that's only that example that sounds weird. But I only care about the word meaning. I'm sorry I can't be too specific about the actual context I will use this word in (it's a bit involved).

Comment: Belle has knots in her hair? Maybe literarily but to explain to an OP, that would be tangles in her hair. Often, a dog or cat with long hair get knots in them. That yes. But then we say knotted, not knots.

Answer (score 1):

Some knots are intentional and some are not.  The intentional ones (those that follow a particular established pattern) are fairly easy to **untie** whereas the accidental knots (e.g. intentional ones that have been botched, knots in a child's hair, knots in headphone wires) can be quite gnarly and those you must  **untangle**.